# First steps with PostgreSQL + Django + South

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, django-south, geodjango

Hi Stackoverflow people,

In the past, I always developed my Django projects locally with sqlite as database platform. Now, I wanted to move to PostgreSQL to take advantage of GIS features, but the transition gives me huge grief.

I have installed postgresql similar to this [post](http://groups.google.com/group/geodjango/browse_thread/thread/eab02419c2890d34) and then followed the [GeoDjango description](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/) for the creation of the database.

Furthermore, I replaced the models class by

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
```

and add

```
geolocation = models.PointField(_('Geo Location'), 
                geography=True, 
                help_text=_('Geolocation with Longitude and Latitude'))

objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Now, before diving deeper into the postgreSQL sphere, I wanted to test the model access through the Django Admin, and I encountered the first error.

When I select the model (which i just modified as mentioned above) in the Admin, I get the following error:

```
**InternalError at /admin/remap/project/**
current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

This error is connected with a wrong sql query, but I am surprised that the Django Admin creates wrong sql statements (used by million developers and it worked fine in the earlier sqlite config).

When I check the django sql statement, I can see the entry for the PointField

```
"geolocation" geography(POINT,4326) NOT NULL,
```

but when I check *psql \d projects*, I can't see the change to the PointField (this is what should cause the error). Since I am using South, I executed

```
./manage.py schemamigration projects --initial
./manage.py migrate projects
```

but I get the message

```
Running migrations for projects:
- Nothing to migrate.
- Loading initial data for projects.
```

**How can I convince south / postgresql that there is something to migrate? 
Do you see any other problem with the transition form SQLite to PostgreSQL?**

Thank you for your answer & help!

Comment: With database already in place, you should first [convert an app](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/convertinganapp.html) to use south, make your changes to the models, then run [`schemamigration`](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/commands.html#schemamigration) so that south creates a migration and finally apply that migration with [`migrate`](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/commands.html#migrate) command. Judging by your question, you changed the model and then ran the schemamigration which didn't have any frozen model to compare the current ones to so it could not detect any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible answer:

Did you syncdb? Often when I'm having trouble with south, I just delete the database and run `manage.py syncdb` from scratch to make sure all my columns are in line. If you want south to ignore migration-enabled apps and just syncdb up to the current version, you can use `manage.py syncdb --all`

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Thank you for your answer. I noticed that the issue has to do something with psql. When I want to drop the particular project table "DROP TABLE project" and afterwards I execute "\d project" - the table is still there. No wonder that psql is not taken the table changes with the GiS changes. Any idea how I could delete the table, is there maybe a forced drop?

Comment: If your question has diverged from the original question, you should edit it to explain the current problem or consider opening a new question if it is drastically different.

I use [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) rather than the command line, so I can't suggest anything in that regard. However, the issue you're describing sounds like you might be editing a different copy of the database than the one Django is using.